# Module vs. Package?

Tags: python, module, package

Whenever I do `from 'x' import 'y'` I was wondering which one is considered the 'module' and which is the 'package', and why it isn't the other way around?

Comment: Packages are containers for modules and other subpackages. In your example `x` is the package and `y` the module, similar to "from the shopping bag take the apple", not the other way around.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

x may be a package or a module and y is something inside that module/package.

A module is a .py file, a package is a folder with an `__init__.py` file. When you import a package as a module, the contents of `__init__.py` module are imported.

Comment: Packages don't necessarily have an `__init__.py` file, and modules aren't necessarily `.py` files.

Comment: You don't need `__init__.py` file in Python 3 and module maybe anything since import hooks were invented but these are exception for the above conventions. 99% of the time the above applies.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations! This helps!

Comment: @geckos Could you please elaborate on those exceptions? Can you add a link for the import hooks? [The official python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) state "The __init__.py files are required to make Python treat directories containing the file as packages.". Are the docs outdated?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#import-hooks @MartinThoma

Comment: @geckos I'm sorry, I still don't get it. If the sys.path is extended, then there is just another path where to look for .py files. So I guess you mean the `meta_path`? I haven't heard of that one before. Do you have a simple example that explains how it is used / why one needs it?

Comment: Yeah I mean meta_path, I never used it though, just heard about it

Answer (score 5):

A Python module is simply a Python source file, which can expose classes, functions and global variables.

When imported from another Python source file, the file name is treated as a namespace.

A Python package is simply a directory of Python module(s).

For example, imagine the following directory tree in `/usr/lib/python/site-packages`:

```
mypackage/__init__.py <-- this is what tells Python to treat this directory as a package
mypackage/mymodule.py
```

So then you would do:

```
import mypackage.mymodule
```

or

```
from mypackage.mymodule import myclass
```